# WCF service to accept xCBL XML via SOAP 1.1

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am tasked with developing a web service end point to accept Purchase Orders from a customer's middleware system.

How do I create a WCF Service that accepts this given payload (example by customer) via SOAP 1.1?

**Following is a excerpt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns0:Order xmlns:ns0 = "rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/ordermanagement/v1_0/ordermanagement.xsd">
  <ns0:OrderHeader>
    <ns0:OrderNumber>
      <ns0:BuyerOrderNumber>3000278673</ns0:BuyerOrderNumber>
    </ns0:OrderNumber>
    <ns0:OrderIssueDate>2012-03-06T14:04:09</ns0:OrderIssueDate>
    <ns0:OrderReferences>
      <ns0:AccountCode>
        <ns1:RefNum xmlns:ns1 = "rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/core/core.xsd">TEST CUSTOMER</ns1:RefNum>
      </ns0:AccountCode>
      <ns0:OtherOrderReferences>
        <ns1:ReferenceCoded xmlns:ns1 = "rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/core/core.xsd">
          <ns1:ReferenceTypeCoded>DocumentNumber</ns1:ReferenceTypeCoded>


    <ns1:ReferenceTypeCodedOther>3000278673</ns1:ReferenceTypeCodedOther>
      <ns1:PrimaryReference>
        <ns1:RefNum/>
      </ns1:PrimaryReference>
      <ns1:ReferenceDescription>IDoc Number</ns1:ReferenceDescription>
    </ns1:ReferenceCoded>
  </ns0:OtherOrderReferences>
</ns0:OrderReferences>
```

I tried to create a XSD from this and generate classes via that but it failed because it couldn't recognise certain types.

Full Documents: ([WSDL definition](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjgxtmfapuoprt4/PurchaseOrder.wsdl?dl=0)) ([XCBL_PO_SOAP definition](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9mxy6pdnhyb03t/PurchaseOrder.xml?dl=0)) ([xCBL Schema](http://www.xcbl.org/xcbl40/distribution.shtml))

I have two questions

**1. How do I create the required service interface from this?**

Or Alternatively

**2. When the supplier transmits the above payload can I model my wcf service to just accept a string and then later use LINQ to query the XML?** When the customer says they use xCBL and SOAP 1.1 is this a viable approach?

```
        //Example
        public string SubmitPurchaseOrder(string XMLPayload){
          return ProcessXmlThroughLinq(XMLPayload);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is facing similar issues use the svcutil.exe.

```
//The WSDL file(s) is in C:\test\.
svcutil.exe /t:code /serviceContract /out:"C:\test\PurchaseOrder.cs" "C:\test\*"
```

PS. Don't worry about it not having any SOAPAction in SOAP Headers. The message body namespace will indicate to the service what operation to use.